# Vector element duplication when capacity is reached

Tags: c++, vector, stl, undefined-behavior

In the program as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> v{ std::make_shared<int>() };

    for ( auto i = v.capacity() - v.size() + 1; i-- > 0; )
        v.push_back( v.back() );

    for ( auto i = v.capacity() - v.size() + 1; i-- > 0; )
        v.insert( v.end(), --v.end(), v.end() );

    for ( const auto & p : v )
    {
        std::cout << ( p ? "valid_ptr" : "null" ) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some compilers output (Visual Studio, ellcc):

```
valid_ptr
valid_ptr
valid_ptr
```

while others (gcc, clang, icc) output:

```
valid_ptr
valid_ptr
null
```

Is it right to assume that duplication of the last element using `push_back` always works correctly even when the vector reaches its capacity and needs to be reallocated?

And at the same time the duplication of the last element using `insert` is an undefined or implementation-specific behavior?

Comment: It is not the `insert` that's undefined behavior in the shown code. It's the `push_back`.

Comment: Why would you not run `push_back()` and `insert()` separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v.insert( v.end(), --v.end(), v.end() )` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of violating prerequisites of the standard library function. Table 87 in **[sequence.reqmts]/4** says, among other things:

> `a.insert(p,i,j)`
> *Requires:* `i` and `j` are not iterators into `a`.

---

`v.push_back( v.back() );` is guaranteed to work, I believe. See [DR#526](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#526) saying "`vector::insert(iter, value)` is required to work because the standard doesn't give permission for it not to work." `push_back` should work for the same reason.

There's a broader class of problems discussed in [DR#2164](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2164), whereby `emplace` may take an arbitrary number of arguments, some of which may refer to elements of the container and/or sub-objects thereof. The consensus seems to be that the implementation should be required to make it work.